# Is it possible select a field if it contains specific text in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I'd like to select by attributes within the field **NAME** that contain "Mt" and "Morris".

Using .format() doesn't work and I've been unable to use search cursor to produce the needed result. Any ideas?

```
TWP_name = "Mt_Morris"
county_name = "Genesee"
countyandTWP_name = county_name+"_"+TWP_name

identifyPLSSbyTWP_name = "\"NAME\"= '{0}'".format(TWP_name)

in_layer_or_view = "TWP_Minor_Civil_Divisions_NAD_83_Michigan"
selection_type = "NEW_SELECTION"
where_clause = identifyPLSSbyTWP_name
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(in_layer_or_view, selection_type, where_clause)

arcpy.management.CopyFeatures("TWP_Minor_Civil_Divisions_NAD_83_Michigan", countyandTWP_name)

m.clearSelection()
```

Comment: The '_' character only matches a single character in a `like` expression (as opposed to equivalence); you seem of want an `or` or something exotic with regexp syntax (which is only available with some data source formats).

Comment: @Vince I'm a little unsure how to use a regexp syntax in this context with or without an `or` . I tried and failed pretty beautifully. I'll keep trying of course!

Comment: Since you are working with publicly available data, i.e., MI minor civil divisions, why not ask your actual question instead of a hypothetical?  Since there is no Hobbes county in MI, nor Mt Stupendous township, people can't look at the data to come up with specific responses.

Comment: @bixb0012 that's good point, I'm used to working with data I cannot share so by habit I change things. I have updated my post!

Comment: regexp isn't going to work unless you're using an RDBMS that supports it (and each supports it differently). Neither shapefile nor file geodatabase SQL flavors would support regexp.

Comment: You state that ".format() doesn't work," what exactly isn't working?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error including traceback.  Or is it unexpected results?  What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question, "Is it possible [to] select a field if it contains specific text in ArcGIS?"  The short answer is "yes," while the longer answer is to a slightly different question, "how does one select a field if it contains specific text in ArcGIS."

As others have already pointed out in comments, how text is selected using SQL in ArcGIS can vary depending on the data source, so it is important to always state the data source in the question when asking SQL-related questions.

As much as SQL is standardized via **ISO/IEC 9075 Information Technology -- Database languages SQL**, the implementation of the standards vary across products, not to mention all the functionality that goes beyond the standards.  For basic pattern matching in text, the <like predicate> has been part of the SQL standard from its beginning in 1986, and its implementation is quite consistent across most data sources.  For more advanced pattern matching in text, the <similar predicate> was introduced into the SQL standard in 1999 to support regular expression patterns; however, SIMILAR TO has not been implemented very broadly across database and data processing systems even though it has been around for nearly 25 years.  It is common for regular expression to be supported through custom keywords instead of SIMILAR TO across various products.

In this specific instance, the pattern matching seems basic and should be accomplished across a wide range of data sources using the same <like predicate>, or even possibly a more basic equality comparison predicate.

Looking at the sample code, and making an assumption the data is formatted that same as [Minor Civil Divisions (Cities & Townships) | State of Michigan](https://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/Michigan::minor-civil-divisions-cities-townships-/explore), I think the issue may be mixing syntax between the a comparison predicate and the like predicate.  With an equality comparison predicate, there are no wildcards with text, so two text values are compared literally using the collation rules of the data source or data processing system.  The like predicate introduces a couple wildcard characters for pattern matching in text, so two text values don't have to be exactly equal, they can be "like" each other.

The `NAME` field in the Minor Civil Divisions dataset does not contain underscores between parts of the name, so doing an equality comparison of `NAME = 'Mt_Morris'` will not return any records; however, doing a like comparison of `NAME LIKE 'Mt_Morris'` will return records because the underscore character represents any single character, including a space.

Although replacing `=` with `LIKE` in `identifyPLSSbyTWP_name` will make the code work, and Mt Morris is a name only in Genesee county, the county and minor civil division pairing is purely manual at this point.  It is  possible to use Select Layer By Location to find the county or counties that minor civil divisions are within, but that starts to go beyond the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro, then nowadays I would use:

```
identifyPLSSbyTWP_name = f"NAME = '{TWP_name}'"
```

If that does not select a record that you expect it to then include a screenshot of your attribute table.

Also, I recommend using the single step `arcpy.analysis.Select()` rather than `arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute()` followed by `arcpy.management.CopyFeatures()`.